# Pass an array parameter to a service on AMFPHP Backoffice

Tags: php, flash, amf, amfphp

In AMFPHP Backoffice is possible to test a service passing parameters. But, when a parameter is an Array, how to test?

See the parameter customers on below image, and the Exception.
[image]

Comment: What version are you using? I recall that a version was released where this didn't work, but it's been fixed since. Try with the latest maybe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm using an old version of AMFPHP Backoffice in a legacy application that simply can not update the AMF. So, I solved by passing a json encoded string and decoding it on php app.